# Java - Recognise sent-to-one and sent-to-all messages from server, on the client-side

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a server/client application that allows multiple clients to be connected to the server at any given time.
For each client, the server sets up a `ClientHandler` object that has an input and output stream to the client connected at this socket. Through this connection, the client is free to send a number of messages to the server at any point throughout the running of the program, and the server will respond according to the message.

What I need to implement is a mechanism that sends, at certain times, messages to all currently-connected clients. I have done this by storing all the output streams to clients in an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` that will allow the same message to be sent to all clients.

What I am struggling with is this:

When a message is received that is individual to the client, the client GUI is updated accordingly (only a select number of messages can be sent, so there only a select number of possible responses-from-server, dealt with by client-side if statements). However, when a message is received by the client that was sent to all clients, I would like the client to update the GUI quite differently.

Considering that both forms of input come from the same input stream, I can see this being difficult, and I anticipate that I will have to declare any methods that cause output using the `PrintWriter` will have to be made `synchronized`. However, is there a way to process the different inputs while using the same `PrintWriter` at all? Would this have to be done using further `if` statements or could it be done using a separate `Thread` on the client side that handles messages sent to all clients?

Thanks for any advice, if you think you can help then feel free to ask for parts of my existing code!

Mark

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You talk about the server side (sending messages to all clients), then you talk about the client side (updating the GUI) and then you suddenly bring in threads which belong to the server, or the client? Looks like you have separate issues here, but you're mixing them. For the message part, you obviously need to mark the broadcast messages somehow in your protocol, and that has nothing to do with thread synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for this, when you say 'mark the broadcast messages somehow', do you mean something like sending a boolean before the content of the message, that can be detected client-side? @SergeyTachenov

Comment: I can't say without knowing the details of your protocol. Is it something that you're free to redesign? What format does it use? Can it be extended or redesigned? For example, if it uses XML messages, then just adding a “broadcast='true'” attribute would to the job. “Sending a boolean before the content” also sounds similar, albeit too naive for a well-defined protocol.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been looking into it and have been told I definitely do need two threads on the client-side. One for individual messages and one for 'broadcasts'. I'm assuming that the marking of the broadcast messages could still work in this way, just with the other client thread calling `wait()` if a broadcast message is detected? @SergeyTachenov

Comment: Two threads on one stream don't make any sense whatsoever. You can have *three* streams, though: one receiving all messages and putting them into two `BlockingQueue`s, other two threads reading from their respective queues (this way you don't have to use the low-level `wait()`, which is ugly). But you still need some way to distinguish between those messages.

Comment: Or even better, instead of using threads directly, use two single-threaded executors and pass messages as `Runnable` tasks for execution. It's a good idea to avoid low-level threading tools as much as possible (`Thread`, `wait()` / `notify()`, `synchronized`, `volatile`...).

Comment: And even then, it still doesn't make sense. If you need to update GUI according to those messages, then why so many threads? Just forward messages from the receiving thread to the GUI thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or whatever similar tool you have available for your GUI framework of choice. You really need to provide details if you want your question answered (instead of wasting 50 reputation on the bounty, which won't help you if the question is impossible to answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     When your clients connect to the server, your server creates a Socket for it, here it is Socket socket = ss.accept();, your socket variable will be holding that client.
```

now if you just keep adding your client socket to a arraylist in your while loop, you will have a list of clients actively connected with your server like:

after the accept:

```
  clients = new ArrayList<DataOutputStream>();
  Socket socket = ss.accept();
  os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  clients.add(os);
```

Now as you have all the clients in that clients arraylist, you can loop through it, or with some protocol define which client should i send the data after reading.

Answer (score 3):

You are first of all lacking a protocol between your server and your clients!

Obviously the server can send two types of messages "response" and "broadcast".
A rather simple approach is tagging your messages: e.g. prefix your mesages with "R" if it is a response to a request and with "B" if it is an unattended broadcast message. (This all depends how communication between server and clients is intended to be performed.)

Whether your client needs different threads for coping with the messages is a completly different story. Having different threads is useful if the processing activity within your client would prevent timely reads of the socket. Then you might consider having an I/O thread that is doing communications and is dispatching the messages to different "handlers" (could be other threads) for processing. (This I/O thread also can remove the tag such that existing processing code need not learn about the lower protocol with the server.)

An analogous reasoning might apply to your server side. Depending on the dynamics of interactions and processing of requests, you might use several threads. Then you should have one that is doing I/O with the clients and others that are doing the work (generating responses or broadcast messages)

Comment: Hi there, you have raised a very interesting point that I feel is what I may have been looking for. You mention "dispatching the messages to different handlers", which is something that could work in my situation. I have been looking for a way to pass messages to another thread but have been unable to find anything suitable. In my current version I have settled for two threads sharing the same `Scanner` object but don't like this at all. Could you possibly add an example of passing the processed message to another thread? Thanks

Comment: Most simple would be a synchronized list or queue shared by the threads, where one thread is inserting _message_ instances and the other is reading the messages. You might read up about **BlockingQueue** for getting synchronisation on empty queue easily.

Comment: I've been told not to use BlockingQueue, as I have to follow the specification provided. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: You may use any class implementing `Collection` provided you yourself deal with necessary synchronisation. Especially you need to get a clear picture what should happen when there is no message to be processed to a thread that should read messages. If it just will drop by occasionally for looking whether there is a message it's one way. Waiting for a new message needs blocking on a reasonable object. This is what BlockingQueue would have brought in. But you can program this yourself using notify/wait calls. Is there a reason for banning BlockingQueue?

Comment: This is a part of an assignment and we haven't yet been taught BlockingQueue, which means there'd be no credit for any coding using those methods. What you described sounds like my exact problem. Is there any chance you could post a very generic example of how to 'ignore' irrelevant messages in a thread using manual methods? This is where I've really been struggling to get my head around it. Thanks

Comment: Then go and look what you have already being taught and take that to compose a solution. I have the imploression that this "ignore irrelevant messages" is the wrong track you are on. Having differnt types of messages requires a unique handler that reads the messages and then checks what do do with them. If you already had some code that read messages this is the very place to insert the new functionality. Just add another case for dealing with the new kind of message being received there. Threads and concurrent processing come into play later in the design process.